# Checking for file conflicts using the sync framework

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I have been trying to build a sort of an update mechanism using the Microsoft Sync framework which would check for changes in one folder(A) and update the same on the other(B). I have a problem where my sync always overwrites the file on the other folder(B). This happens when I set the ConflictResolutionPolicy to source wins or merge. I want the user to have the ability to say Yes overwrite or No skip. Probably like the windows dialog box when we are copying files and when there is a conflict between files of the same name. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me or would give me a lead to some documentation on how to get this dialog box functionality when there is a conflict between files.

This is what I do right now but I can't get it to do anything. There are files that are of the same name but different time-stamps which has to trigger a conflict but doesn't unfortunately in my case.

```
    private void OnItemConflicting(object sender, ItemConflictingEventArgs args)
    {
        args.SetResolutionAction(ConflictResolutionAction.SaveConflict);
        Console.WriteLine(" Conflict detected for item " + args.DestinationChange.ItemId.ToString());
    }

    private void OnItemConstraint(object sender, ItemConstraintEventArgs args)
    {
        args.SetResolutionAction(ConstraintConflictResolutionAction.RenameDestination);
        ConstraintConflictResolutionAction.RenameDestination.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(" Constraint conflict detected" + args.DestinationChange.ItemId.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set the conflict resolution to source wins, then of course it will overwrite the destination.

displaying the dialog box is outside of the framework's scope already.

you can handle an event when a conflict fires or you can preview the changes before you sync. you can display or prompt the user for the options to resolve the conflict

both scenarios are covered in the documentation that gets installed with the SDK

Comment: Yes you are right. If the ConflictresolutionAction is set to source win it overwrites but if the ConflictresolutionAction is set to SaveConflict it seems to just not do anything or trigger anything.